# Is there any difference between" yet " and "and yet"?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Despite what has just been said:

They are SYNONYMS nevertheless.

> It's a small car, yet it's surprisingly spacious.
>
> He has a good job, and yet he never seems to have any money.

Considering the explanations above, would you tell me if there is any difference between the followings?

Yet

And yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means, putting the word *and* would simply intensifies the matter. Because *and* also means *in addition* or *something increased*.

> He has a good job, yet he never seems to have any money - a general sentence. 
>   He has a good job, and yet he never seems to have any money - **intensifies the matter** and means it's pity that in spite of having a good job, he does not have money.

Comment: *And* is never a preposition.

Comment: @snailplane one **and** one is two. Here, **and** is a preposition. but I'm removing from this

Comment: @MaulikV [Your favorite dictionary](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=and) is wrong again, I'm afraid.

Comment: @snailplane what is it in that sentence then?

Comment: A coordinator (or "coordinating conjunction", if you prefer).

Answer (score 2):

The 'and' is optional and can be dropped in this case. For me, there's no real difference, apart from the word count.

It's similar to dropping 'that' in the following sentence:

> I think that you cause problems.
>   I think you cause problems.

These two sentences have the same meaning: you can simply not add the 'that' in there. It's the same here as the 'and' is purely optional. No change in meaning.